# weakly chained diagonally dominant matrices and basic definitions

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I would like some direction on where to look for more information about directed graphs of a square matrix and the connection to weakly chained diagonally dominant matrices.  I want very basic definitions that for some reason I cannot find in wikipedia searches on M-matrices and obviously diagonal dominance, weak diagonal dominance, and weakly chained diagonal dominance, which is a small piece of my attempt to address boundary conditions of a reaction diffusion problem.  Any help would be appreciated - textbook references that give explicit definitions or simple examples would be preferential. Thank you all

Comment: Have you read this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_chained_diagonally_dominant_matrix?